# php remove URLs from form submission

Tags: php

I have a parish website that I am maintaining. The site has a parish registration form on it. Yesterday someone submitted the form with spam. The submitter supplied an inappropriate web address in one of the fields.

I'm fairly confident this was not a bot form submission as I use a recapcha and honeypot to fend off bots.

What I'm trying to figure out is how on the processing page to look at all the text entry fields and scrub URLs.

Since the language is PHP:

```
 function scrubURL(field){
     if($_POST[field] contains **SomeURL**){
         $field = str_replace(***SomeURL***, "", $_POST[field])
     } else{
         $field = $_POST[field];
     }
     return $field;
 }
```

I'm just not sure to check the field to see if it contains a URL.

I'm planning to scrub URLs by calling:

```
 $first = scrubURL($first);
 $last = scrubURL($last);
 $address = scrubURL($address);
```

I will then use $first, $last & $address in the mail that gets sent to the parish office.

Comment: Look at function `parse_url`.

Comment: That function requires a URL and breaks it into its component parts. I want to see if the string contains a URL anywhere in it and remove it if it does.

Comment: And what makes a URL a URL? An absolute URL will begin with `http://` or `https://`. Is that what you want to be looking for?

Comment: with or without. Could be badsite.com or www.badsite.com or http:// www.badsite.com or badsite.com?id=27 I would have no way of knowing what someone could type in the form. maybe I need a regex to compare the string against?

Comment: By the way, your PHP code is not compilable. For example, `field` needs to be `$field` and`first` should be `$first` to avoid a warning, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will recognize URLs and replace then with empty strings. Just realize that lots of thing, such as `wx.yz` look like valid URLs.

```
function scrubURL($field)
{
    //return preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)*)(?:[?&][^?$]+=[^?&]*)*@i', '', $_POST[$field]);
    return preg_replace("#((https?://|ftp://|www\.|[^\s:=]+@www\.).*?[a-z_\/0-9\-\#=&])(?=(\.|,|;|\?|\!)?(\"|'|«|»|\[|\s|\r|\n|$))#iS", '', $_POST[$field]);

}
```

The parameter, `$field`, has to be a string, such as "email" corresponding to  `$_POST["email"]`

```
<?php

$_POST = [
    'email' => 'something www.badsite.com?site=21&action=redirect else',
];

function scrubURL($field)
{
    return preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)*)(?:[?&]\S+=\S*)*@i', '', $_POST[$field]);
}

echo scrubURL('email');
```

Prints:

```
something  else
```

Comment: I like that. But it's not catching ?site=21&action=redirect at the end of a site like www.badsite.com?site=21&action=redirect. might you be able to update the regex? I'm not that good with them and am not getting it to work.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It's difficult finding the "ultimate" regex. There is always one better.

Comment: I also think this is error prone as I have hinted. Why not just search for the string "pornhub" and replace it? :-)

Comment: I don't think I could devise a list of strings long enough to catch all the possible sites. plus extensions, prefixes, etc. In the end I've used the above regex to find the occurrence of a URL and  halt processing of the form since no one needs to submit URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is an easy way to evaluate fields for possible URL markers. Something like the following would remove much of it (though, given how many shapes URLs can come in, not everything):

```
$_POST = [
    'first' => 'actualname',
    'last' => 'something http://url.com/visit-me', 
    'middle' => 'hello www.foobar.com spammer', 
    'other' => 'visit https://spammery.us/ham/spam spamming', 
    'more' => 'spam.tld', 
];

// Iterates all $_POST fields, editing the $_POST array in place
foreach($_POST as $key => &$val) {
    $val = scrubUrl($val); 
}

function scrubURL($data)
{
    /* Removes anything that: 
        - starts with http(s):
        - starts with www.
        - has a domain extension (2-5 characters)
        ... ending the match with the first space following the match.
    */
    $data = preg_replace('#\b
        (
        https?:
        |
        www\.
        |
        [^\s]+\.[a-z]{2,5}
        )
        [^\s]+#x', '-', $data);
    return $data;
}

print_r($_POST);
```

Be aware that the last condition, looking for any TLD (.abc) -- and there are lots of them! -- may result in some false positives.

- "sentence.Poor punctuation" would be safe. We're only matching [a-z].However, spam.Com would also pass! Use [a-Z] to match both cases, or add the "`i`" modifier to the regex.
- "my acc.no is 12345" would be removed (potential spammer accountants from Norway?!)

The above process would give you the following filtered data:

```
Array (
    [first] => actualname
    [last] => something -
    [middle] => hello - spammer
    [other] => visit - spamming
    [more] => -
)
```

The regex can definitely be further refined. ^_^

N.B. You may also want to sanitize the incoming data with e.g. `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars` to ensure the website is sending reasonably safe data to your parish.